# Cordova build returns missing plugin.xml

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

When i build my `cordova` project i get an warning message as:

> Missing file:
>   /home/vijay/workspace/Repos_temp/QuickTraq_Android/plugins/nl.x-services.plugins.toast/plugin.xml
>
> Missing file:
>   /home/vijay/workspace/Repos_temp/QuickTraq_Android/plugins/cordova-plugin-device-rotation-vector/plugin.xml

This happens when i add an plugin or remove an plugin also .

This happens just as a warning when i add a plugin or build the project but when i remove the plugin error occurs as

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   '/home/vijay/workspace/Repos_temp/QuickTraq_Android/plugins/com.grumpysailor.cordova-plugin-device-rotation-vector/plugin.xml'
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:290:15)
>       at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/util/xml-helpers.js:121:27)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/dependencies.js:56:35
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Object.module.exports.package.generateDependencyInfo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/dependencies.js:53:45)
>       at runUninstallPlatform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/uninstall.js:218:53)
>       at Function.module.exports.uninstallPlatform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/uninstall.js:81:12)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/plugin.js:205:58
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)

and my plugin remove failed .. Is there an way to resolve this ??

Comment: Could you try to `add` the plugin again (use `phonegap local plugin add`) if in-case you used Cordova's commands. If that still won't work, try cleaning npm's cache with `npm cache clean` and re-install Cordova/Phonegap.

Comment: I tried npm cache clean . I don't want to reinstall cordova is there an work around ??

Comment: May I ask why are you unwilling to re-install Cordova? And what happens when you try to `add` the plugin again?

Comment: I have an working environment and i fear something might happen . So i font prefer to reinstall . When i add the plugin it says already exists.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The **plugin.xml** looks to be missing. The path to each added plugin's plugin.xml should be:

```
 <yourapp>/plugins/<some-plugin>/plugin.xml
```

If you cannot find the **plugin.xml** files in those folders, you will have to manually download it from its git resource. Try adding `device-rotation-vector`'s [xml from here](https://github.com/GrumpySailor/cordova-plugin-device-rotation-vector/blob/master/plugin.xml) and then run:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-device-rotation-vector
```

If it works correctly, do the same for [Toast plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/plugin.xml).

You can find the list of plugins installed using:

```
cordova plugin list
```

Comment: Exactly did the same and worked !! I think there could be an error while removing the plugin last time . Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to know. And yeah, it could be while you tried to remove it the last time; that is why you should be careful about every error given by the CLI while adding/removing anything.

Comment: This error could be caused by something else entirely.

Comment: In case this helps, while using Cordova with Ionic, I have noticed that when I'm switching between machines using the same repo after adding a cordova plugin on one machine but not the other, I see the error above; and the solution for me has been to `ionic platform rm android ios` and `ionic platform add android ios`.

Answer (score 11):

Remove folder "plugin_name" in rootApp_folder/plugins/plugin_name and try to add again.

Answer (score 3):

#### SOLVED

Please try to add the plugin from GitHub repository. I had to install `app-preferences` plugin. So, I just did it like:

`$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences`

Answer (score 2):

These solutions not worked for me. I just restarted the command prompt, then everything working fine

Answer (score 0):

Close all Windows that may touch upon the install.  Then try to install again.

W10:... I had an open Command Prompt open to an Android build output folder.  The install was unable to delete a file, which failed the install, until after I closed the Command Prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the plugin folder worked for me, otherwise, both remove and add plugin was giving the same error.

Another method was to remove and re-add platform, but sometimes you have to install the plugins manually before adding the platform.