# Cannot remove cordova plugin using CLI

Tags: cordova

I would like to know how to remove a cordova plugin using CLI. I need to remove one plugin I installed today, but it won't go away.

I installed `apprate` plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-apprate)

Now I want to remove it, but `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-apprate` outputs the following:

```
Uninstalling 2 dependent plugins.
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-globalization from android
Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin 'org.apache.cordova.globalization'. Please try adding it again.
```

This has never happened to me and I am frustrated that this happens. Any ideas?

I've tried to install `org.apache.cordova.globalization` but the issue persists. Also, now I can't remove `org.apache.cordova.globalization` because `apprate` depends on it.

Comment: Have you already tried other SO Question like [here - missing plugin.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232647/cordova-build-returns-missing-plugin-xml)

Comment: are you using the latest version of the plugin? the latest version has a dependency for cordova-plugin-globalization, not for org.apache.cordova.globalization